# How to get an image picker only from DCIM directory

Tags: android, image, camera, android-intent, media

I have to include an image picker in my android app.
I set it like this :

```
Intent intentGallery = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
startActivityForResult(intentGallery, 0);
```

But all the pictures of the SD card are displayed. I only want to show the pictures taken with the camera (in the DCIM folder).

Is it possible to do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not possible.
If necessary, you can implement your own gallery, that will pick images only from

```
    android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
```

and

```
    android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
```

Answer (score 0):

You would use android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI to access images on the device instead of the SD card.

[EDIT]

Browsing the Android source, specifically the Gallery app, I stumbled across

```
public static final String CAMERA_IMAGE_BUCKET_NAME = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/DCIM/Camera";
```

Which I guess is what you are looking for. You can view the full source [here](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/packages/apps/Gallery.git;a=blob;f=src/com/android/camera/ImageManager.java;h=ab7fe9cc7d9211e20d6f357ab5bf74c397b7cc24;hb=HEAD)

Comment: I can't because pictures taken with the camera on android devices are stored in the SD card